# Yacc- How to write action code for assign operation with C structure node

Tags: c, yacc, abstract-syntax-tree

In yacc program,how do we write the action for assign operation using c structure node?

Example:-

```
stmt: stmt stmt ';'
    | exp ';'               {printtree();}
    | bool ';'              {...}
    | VAR ASSIGN exp ';'    {//How to store this value to VAR using node?}
    ...
    ;

exp: exp PLUS exp           {make_operator($1,'+',$3);// which stores a char '+' with  
                             left node to $1 and right node to $3 to the synatx tree
                            }
    | exp MINUS exp         {...}
    ...
    ;
```

It would be of great help if someone can suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that since your Yacc parser is not actually executing the code, but producing an abstract syntax tree (as evidenced by the use of a `make_operator` function in the `PLUS` operation, the same thing is done for the assignment. It could be as simple as:

```
stmt: stmt stmt ';'
    | exp ';'               {printtree();}
    | bool ';'              {...}
    | VAR ASSIGN exp ';'    {$$ = make_operator($1, '=', $3);}
    ...
    ;
```

The actual job of generating the code to perform the assignment will be done by other passes over the syntax tree which is constructed by the parser. Those passes will have to do things like ensuring that `VAR` is actually defined in the given scope and so on, depending on the rules of the language: does it have the right type, is it modifiable, ...

A translation scheme for assignments (at least of a simple scalar variable which fits into a register) is:

1. Generate the code to calculate the address of the assignment target, such that this code leaves the value in a new temporary register, call it `t1`.
2. Generate the code to calculate the value of the expression, leaving it in another register `t2`.
3. Generate the code `mem[t1] := t2` which represents store the value of `t2` into the memory location pointed at by `t1`. (Of course, this intermediate code isn't literally represented by text such as `mem[t1] := t2`, but rather some instruction data structure. The text is just a printed notation so we can discuss it.)